# Pass data in Angular router dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to send data(Object) from one component to another however I am getting an empty result.

Here is my code

***routing module***

```
{ path: 'booking/details', component: DetailsComponent, data: { title: extract('Details'), dataTransfer: '' } },
```

***sending component***

```
this.router.navigate(['/booking/details', this.caseData]);
```

this.caseData looks like this

```
{
  "getAllInfo": {
    "ticket": {
      "internalNum": "12345",
      "comp": "11"
    },
    "caseInfo": {
      "masVolgnommer": "1",
      "masMaand": "1",
      "masJaar": "2010"
    }
  }
}
```

***receiving component***

```
this.caseData = this.route
 .data
 .subscribe(v => console.log(v.dataTransfer));
```

Comment: The values in that array are used to build the URL, not the `data` property. It sounds like you may be better off creating a shared service.

Comment: yes you are correct, I am just passing data from one component to another so doing it through the url is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data property is not needed in your route - without adding data you can bind data as a json and read it `{ path: 'booking/details', component: DetailsComponent }` this is fine to pass data while routing - whereas data property in your route declaration is used to pass data every time when the route is navigated

When you try to navigate `booking/details` everytime you will get data `{title: "Details", dataTransfer: ""}` to read this data you can inject `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`in your constructor and read as

`this.activatedRouteSnapshot.data["title"]`this will return **Details**

In your case if you want to pass data to another component just pass the data as a Json

`this.router.navigate(['/booking/details', { caseData : this.caseData }]);`

Finally you can read the data in the same way mentioned above - `this.activatedRouteSnapshot.data["caseData"]`

Hope this works - Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

set the caseData inside the subscribe method

```
this.route
 .data
 .subscribe(v => {
   this.caseData = v;
   console.log(this.caseData) 
});
```

Comment: this is the response `{title: "Details", dataTransfer: ""}` The data is not getting inserted into the dataTransfer parameter