# How to display recieved form input data to other component in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dom

register.component.html (the form input component)

```
<div class="card-content">

    <form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(Name.value, Email.value)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input type="text" name="Name"
          #Name
          ngModel required>
          <label for="Name">Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">mail_outline</i>
          <input type="text" name="Email"
          #Email
          ngModel
          required
          [pattern]="emailPattern">
          <label for="Email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <button class="btn-large btn-submit"
          type="submit"
          [disabled]='!registerForm.valid'>Start</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
```

register.component.ts
........................................................................................

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { QuizService } from '../shared/quiz.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  emailPattern = '^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$';

  constructor(private route: Router, private quiz: QuizService) { }

  user = {
    username: '',
    email: ''
  };

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(name, email) {
    this.user.username = name;
    this.user.email = email;

    this.route.navigate(['quiz']);
    console.log(this.user.username, this.user.email); // log works!!

  }

}
```

quiz.component.html (here i want to display the data which user entered in register component)
.........................................................

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
    <h3>Welcome to quiz</h3>

    <b>Your Name is: </b> 
    <br>
    <b>Your Email is: </b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202385/pass-data-in-angular-router-dynamically]

Answer (score 3):

```
this.route.navigate(['quiz',{username:username,...}])
```

and in your **quiz component** receive data

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{ console.log(params.username)})
```

don't forget inject the `ActivatedRoute` in your **quiz**

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to accomplish this but I would suggest looking at NgRX Store, if you want a simpler solution then you can use a service:

```
@Injectable({
  provideIn: ‘root’
})
export class SomeService {
  userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>({});
  user$: Observable<User> = this.userSubject;
}
```

In your `RegisterComponent` submit event you will call `someService.userSubject.next(this.user);` and in your `QuizComponent` subscribe to `someService.user$` to pick up the data