# calling a method in app.component.ts from another component in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and trying to learn it. I have a function in app.component.ts which injects a menu to app.component.html and the menu variable is dynamic based on the permission of logged in user, now I want to call this method once the user logged in how can I do it effectively

This is my app.component.ts

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test App';
  constructor(private authService:AuthService){}
  public userName;
  public permission;
  public jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  public menuItems=[];

 setMenu(){
    if(this.authService.loggedIn()){
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
        this.userName = decodedToken.userName;
        this.hospitalName = decodedToken.hospitalName;
        this.permission = decodedToken.permission;
        if(this.permission == 'admin'){
            this.menuItems = this.adminMenuItems;
        }
        else{
            this.menuItems = this.nurseMenuItems;
        }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your auth service, create an Observable that emits each time the login status changes:

```
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';     

private _statusChange$ = new Subject<boolean>();
private loginStatus$ = this._statusChange$.asObservable();

// Whenever the status changes:
this._statusChange$.next(newIsLoggedInValue);
```

Then, inside your component, change your code so it listens to that Observable, like so:

```
this.authService.loginStatus$.subscribe((isLoggedIn) => {
    if(isLoggedIn()){
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
        this.userName = decodedToken.userName;
        this.hospitalName = decodedToken.hospitalName;
        this.permission = decodedToken.permission;
        if(this.permission == 'admin'){
            this.menuItems = this.adminMenuItems;
        } else {
            this.menuItems = this.nurseMenuItems;
        }
    }
})
```

This way, it will fire each time the login status changes

Comment: could you please help me with that part

Comment: @RahulUnnikrishnan With which part?

Comment: Adding observable in authService

Comment: @RahulUnnikrishnan I've added that into my answer? The first bit will show how to create the Observable

Answer (score 0):

Just call it in `ngOnInit()` method which gets triggered when your components loaded

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.setMenu();
    }
  }
```

Make sure you import - `import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

Happy coding !!

Comment: thanks but it won't work as token value is set after ngOnInit()

Comment: Then try to check the permission while `routing` and read the permission on your  `ngOnInit()` and add menu items based on it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202385/pass-data-in-angular-router-dynamically/53202676#53202676] hope this will help you - thanks