# Distinguish router path in Angular

Tags: angular

Angular routing:

```
{
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./test/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: AnyComponent
  },
```

There is any mechanism for distinguish routing path, which are was provided from url, f.e.

I. If the User provide/enter in browser url -> `http://example.com/10`

```
- will be calling below routing

path: '**',
    component: AnyComponent
```

II. If in component, we are using the router navigate:

```
 this.router.navigate([`${this.someData.id}]);
 
 will be calling:
 
path: ':id',
loadChildren: () => import('./test/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule)
```

So I would like to select/control which component will be loading, according to how the proper url will be provided (By User or By Code)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, using the code based approach leverages the same mechanism as the user-entered route. So I don't think that there is a built-in way to distinguish them.

Alternate ideas:

1. Use different routes. For example: `http:/example.com/10` and `http://example.com/id/10` so that they can be captured and processed differently.
2. Pass data to the route using something like shown here: [Pass data in Angular router dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202385/pass-data-in-angular-router-dynamically)

Comment: But I must use that same path. But need any mechanism that say -> if navigate to that same path from code, the load component must be different than if we navigate from URL path (browser).

Comment: Did you check out Alternate Idea #2 above?

Comment: Hmm but there are totally 2 different components, views... I am thinking it will be a good solution.

Comment: IMHO, I'd also wonder, from a user perspective, whether it would be confusing/unexpected to have the same URL lead to different views. But this is out of scope of your question. :-)

Comment: Mechanism for dynamic search url params. F.e. app/sth -> we will check if sth exists in our 'search database' - if yes, I would like to load search results page for 'sth' param. And the best solution (SEO point of view), will be URL with /sth, not /search-results/sth.

Answer (score 1):

this should be done on the **component** and you should ***not*** be doing wild card routing on the root route.  this will cause you state issue on the angular router.

so what you **should** do is create a root component also called a **parent** in your lazy loaded route then call the child from there.

IE number/:id.

**NOT** :id - if you do this - this will create many problems for yourself because all routes will be caught by the :id route which in effect is the exact same as the catchall route **. the causation would be no matter what route the users takes unless its strong typed and placed before this route - **every** single route would go there so if someone went too contacts as an example it would be caught by the same route that you want the number 10 to go to.

the angular router is incredibly powerful is you use it properly - but I think for you its a logic thing, you need to reshape your routes so that they can be maintained.

in terms of the getting the end of the url from the route.  I've provided an example for you.

```
constructor(router: Router){}

ngOnInit(){ const routeName = 
this.router.url.split('/').pop();
if(routerName==='10'){
do something here
}
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Or maybe another point of view -> can we have different routing, different component, but URL in browser will be that same?

Comment: yes you can do that we do it a lot - we use one component as a shell basically to load other components into the viewport based upon conditions - on the html you can use something called ngSwitchCase and bind it to the router name.